# restas dias a fecha actual

Tags: java

buen dia necesito restarle 6 dias a la fecha actual con el siguiente metodo, tengo el codigo actual pero me resta muchos años y solo necesito que me reste 6 dias de la fecha actual, gracias

```
public void cambioFechaCompra(DetalleDocumentoDto detalle) {
  if (detalle.getCodFormaGeneracion().equals("2")) {
    detalle.setFechaCompra(new Date(-6));
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Probaste con la función getDay()?, esto te devuelve el día de la semana en el que te encuentras. A ello le restas 6

Comment: me puedes indicar como ponerlo en el codigo por favor

Comment: La etiqueta [tag:javascript] no es correcta para el código que muestras. Por casualidad no estás usando [tag:java]?

Comment: Buenas elimino mi respuesta dado que ha cambiado el lenguaje en el que queria la solucion

Comment: @RobertoMoralesFumero así no haya modificado la etiqueta, haz puesto un código con partes de java y javascript... se me hace raro que no te hayas dado cuenta de eso :)

Comment: Como comente, he escrito el lo necesario para que se restaran los dias en Javascript y despues he ido cambiando en el editor de esta pagina. Obviamente que va a haber dos lenguajes diferentes dado que he usado su codigo de Java y el mio de Javascript se lo he integrado al de @andersonandres directamente en SO

Comment: Intenta con `detalle.setFechaCompra(new Date(new Date().getTime()-86400000*6));`

Comment: Usa esta función para restar días LocalDateTime fechaRestada = fechaActual.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime().minusDays(dias); Luego lo conviertes a Date Puedes aprender más de esto en la siguiente página:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-date-to-localdate-and-localdatetime

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza Calendar de la siguiente forma:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance().add(Calendar.DATE, -6);
detalle.setFechaCompra(cal.getTime());
```

getInstance te trae la fecha actual y la función `add` suma o resta, positivo o negativo, determinado número según el primer parámetro en este caso días.